# java threading how to sequence the execution of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three threads named thread 1, thread 2 and thread 3 .

how to sequence thread execution?

like thread 3 follows thread 2 and thread 2 follows thread 1?
Actually please refer to my solution, in my case thread 1 joins main and while executing(thread 1) 
at the end creates thread 2 and so on..
i'm asking is it a correct approach?

Comment: use `join()` if you want to wait for complete execution of threads one after another.

Comment: please refer to my solution, i'm using join only for thread t1(with main) for rest it's simple sequential flow.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> t.join();
>
> causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread
>   terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a
>   waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS
>   for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as
>   long as you specify.

Comment: plz refer to my solution

Answer (score 0):

package sequencing;

class T1 implements Runnable {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("thread executing is : "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    T2 tr2 = new T2();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(tr2, "t2");
    t2.start();
}
```

}

class T2 implements Runnable {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("thread executing is : "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    T3 tr3 = new T3();
    Thread t3 = new Thread(tr3, "t3");
    t3.start();
}
```

}

class T3 implements Runnable {

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("thread executing is : "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

}

public class Sequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

```
    T1 tr1 = new T1();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(tr1, "t1");
    t1.start();
    t1.join();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.println("main finishing..");
}
```

}

//this is how i'm doing it..is there a better way of doing it? like t3 join t2 join t1?